# Google Places API returns different place_id for the same city

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I am using Google Places API for android. In which I am getting different place_id for the same city. Earlier it returns `ChIJwe1EZjDG5zsRaYxkjY_tpF0` as a place_id for MUMBAI but now it returns `ChIJwe1EZjDG5zsRaYxkjY_tpF2aBhpNdW1iYWksIE1haGFyYXNodHJhLCBJbmRpYQ` for MUMBAI.

Can someone please explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fix that was introduced on December 22, 2016.

Please have a look at this bug in the public issue tracker and explanation in comment #30:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11107#c30

The issue that many users experienced was that after cleanup of the data many duplicated place IDs were deleted and place autocomplete was changed to avoid zero_results for deleted places. So, this long place ID allows to resolve addresses or places even if the place ID was deleted to the correct short place ID.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem but with a whole lot of cities. Apparently the place_id changed for many cities without prior notice or it is a recent bug.

In any case, you can compare the current response (for Paris) [here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?&input=Paris&types=geocode&key=AIzaSyDqrmmrjErESrHp8IYRF7zYga6JyjINpNk) with Google's own documentation using [Paris](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) as example.

The place_id for both requests is different, however, the id of the object is the same. So, where does this inconsistency comes from?